# DB2 joins difficulties

Tags: join, db2, bi-temporal

I have the following situation (simplified):

2 BiTemp Tables

- basicdata (id, btmp_tsd, name, prename)
- extendeddata (id, btmp_tsd, basicid, codename, codevalue)

In extendeddata, there can be multible entries for one basicdata with each a different codename and value.

I have to create an SQL to select all rows which have changed since a specified time. For the basicdata table this is relatively simple:

```
SELECT ID, BTMP_TSD, NAME, PRENAME
FROM BASICDATA BD
WHERE BTMP_TSD  =
               (SELECT MAX(BTMP_TSD)
                  FROM BASICDATA BD2
                 WHERE BD2.ID             =  BD.PRTNR_ID
                   AND BD2.BTMP_TSD      >  :MINTSD
                   AND BD2.BTMP_TSD      <= :MAXTSD
               )
ORDER BY ID
WITH UR
```

Now I will need to Join on the second table to get the codevalue for the codename 'test'. The problem is, it may not exist, in this case, the row should be collected anyway. But if there is a row but not within the timerange, I should not get a result.

I hope I was able to explain my issue. Joins are one of the things I still don't see trough...

Edit:
Okay here's a sample

```
basicdata:
id,btmp_tsd,name,prename
1,2013-05-25,test,user
2,2013-06-26,user,two
3,2013-06-26,peter,hans
1,2013-06-20,test,us3r
2,2013-10-30,us3r,two

extendeddata:
id,btmp_tsd,basicid,codename,codevalue
1,2013-05-25,1,superadmin,1
2,2013-06-26,3,admin,1
3,2013-11-25,1,superadmin,0
```

Okay now having these entries and I want all userid's which have had any changes since **2013-10-01** I should get

> User1 (Because the extendeddata superadmin had a change)
>
> User2 (Had a Name change and I want him even tough he has no entry on the extendeddata table)
>
> not User3 (He has an entries on both tables but it's not in the specified range)

Comment: Can you add some sample data and the expected results?

Comment: I added some sample data and what I expect

Answer (score 0):

The following query should do what you want.

```
select * 
from basicdata b left outer join extendeddata e on b.id=e.basicid
where b.btmp_tsd >= '2013-10-01'
  or e.btmp_tsd >= '2013-10-01'
```

DISCLAIMER: I didn't test the sql. So syntax might not be 100% perfect.

Comment: The problem is, due to the tables being bi-temporal this won't be as easy as this